# Confusion moving from mysql to mysqli with strange error message

Tags: php

this is my first attempt at mysqli after moving over from mysql so sorry for asking stupid questions but its a bit of a learning curve :-S.

Im currently using the following to try and pull some photo data from the database, but am getting an error but I cant see for the life of me why.

```
     <?php
             $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `shop`
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">';
     echo '<h2 class="item_name">'.$row[filename].'</h2>';
     echo '<p>  <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"><br>';
     echo '<span class="item_price">&pound;'.$row[price].'</span><br>';
     echo '<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
             ?>
    <span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> items - <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>
```

The error I am getting is :

```
query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']'); } while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ echo '
'; echo '
'.$row[filename].'

'; echo '

'; echo '£'.$row[price].'
'; echo ' Add to Cart

'; echo '
'; } ?> 16 items - $243.95 Checkout
```

which in comparison to mysql die errors means nothing at all to me ?.

Comment: But what error do you have? You gave us a part of your code, not an error.

Comment: That isn't a mysqli error message; that's just a copy of half your program. Are you sure you don't have a stray question mark in the code...? maybe something like this.... `$db-?>query` ? That would trigger PHP to drop back into HTML output mode rather than running the rest of the code.

Comment: That sounds like your PHP code isn't being run at all, and the first closing `>` which occurs in `$db->` is interpreted as the closing of an unknown HTML tag. Are you running a web server?

Comment: And does this file have a .php extension? The file appears to have been served as plain HTML. View the page source and you should see _all your code_.

Comment: Do you have other php code below from what you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, Michael is right.
It is not wrong HEREDOC syntax as I thought before but your code just never executed.

If you look into *page source*, which you ought to look into as a developer, you will see your whole script.

The problem has nothing to do with mysqli anyway.

Comment: for a short query like this, that is probably good advice, but it isn't an solution to the question.

Comment: I think Your common sense  has a point, it looks like the OP's string is not terminated

Comment: @periklis It's called a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), begins with `<<<SQL` and is terminated by the `SQL;`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I know what it is, but the OP's problem looks as if the specific heredoc is not terminated where he thinks it is, and perhaps it's terminated further down. That would explain why the error message contains his actual PHP code. For example, if there are spaces before the SQL;

Comment: Yes your right !, it isnt executing the code, hmm now that's opened another can of worms, I shall look into it as im not sure why :-S